# Issue using Contact Group delete on Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.1, android-contentresolver, contactgroups

I have this code to delete a Contact Group

```
public void delete(Activity act,String[] args) {
        try {
            int b=act.getContentResolver().delete(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,"_ID=?", args);

            Toast.makeText(act, "Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //notify registered observers that a row was updated
            act.getContentResolver().notifyChange(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            Toast.makeText(act, TAG + " Delete Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I call the method like

```
private void processDelete(long rowId) {
        String[] args = { String.valueOf(rowId) };

        objItem.delete(this, args);
        cur.requery();
    }
```

I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

The ID is passed ok.

The b value returns 1, but the delete is not performed, on activity restart I still see the record in the list.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my miss:

When quering the existing records I had to add a where clause to denote that I do not want `deleted=1` values, as the values are not delete instantly, they are flagged as deleted.

```
Cursor managedCursor = act.managedQuery(contacts, projection, 
                ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=0", 
                null,
                ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " ASC");
        return managedCursor;
```

Comment: can i permanently delete a group from device where later ' ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED + "=0",' checking is not required?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add where clause saying that.
If you wont to instantly delete items in database and not flag them as deleted, add this row to you URI.

```
mUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"1").build();
//and then call your delete function with URI appended like this.
mResolver.delete(mUri,null, null);
```

that flag: CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER set to 1 will delete row instantly.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yep, this wins over Pentium10's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can delete contact group using this

```
    private void deletaAllInGroup(Context context, long groupId)
           throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
    values.put(ContactsContract.Groups._ID, groupId);
    getContentResolver().delete(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,values.toString(),null);
        }
```