# How to delete a contacts group in android programmatically?

Tags: android

How to programmatically delete a particular android contacts Group?

I tried this,

[Issue using Contact Group delete on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353015/issue-using-contact-group-delete-on-android)

not working to me. Please tell me any ideas or suggestions. It is really help to me.

Advance Thanks!!!

Comment: we want delete All contacts...

Comment: No. I don't want to delete contacts. I want to delete group only. Already I have a program to remove contacts from group. And Thanks for support

Comment: Android Contacts group. Like Co-workers, Family, Favorites. Please see this link. It will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026025/get-contacts-from-contact-group-based-on-group-id

Answer (score 4):

I find a way to delete a group properly.
You need to get the id of the group you want to remove with an appropriate query, and then you can delete this group with this id and the Groups.CONTENT_URI.

I post an example below (just adapt it to your code).

```
// First get the id of the group you want to remove
long groupId = null;
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver.query(Groups.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] {
        Groups._ID
    }, Groups.TITLE + "=?", new String[] {
        yourGroupTitle // Put here the name of the group you want to delete
    }, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            groupId = cursor.getLong(0);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

// Then delete your group
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> mOperations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

// Build the uri of your group with its id
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupId).buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
        .build();
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(uri);
mOperations.add(builder.build());

// Then apply batch
try {
    mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, mOperations);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("########## Exception :", ""+e.getMessage());
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: The most important line is `.appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")` to permanently delete the group.

Answer (score 1):

First find all contact-ids having a specific group id. Then creating a `ContentProviderOperation` for each contact to be deleted, and last apply the list of delete operations.

```
private void deletaAllInGroup(Context context, long groupId)
   throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException{
    String where = String.format("%s = ?", GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID);
    String[] whereParmas = new String[] {Long.toString(groupId)};
    String[] colSelection = new String[] {Data.CONTACT_ID};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            colSelection, 
            where, 
            whereParmas, 
            null);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = 
        new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    // iterate over all contacts having groupId 
    // and add them to the list to be deleted
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){ 
        String where = String.format("%s = ?", RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);
        String[] whereParams = new String[]{Long.toString(cursor.getLong(0))};

        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(where, whereParams)
        .build());
    }

    context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(
        ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations );
}
```

Comment: I tried this code. In simulator, contacts only deleted in group, but group not deleted. 

In mobile, contacts and group both are not deleted. (I tried htc wildfire s)

Comment: You want to delete the group name also.?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to delete a Group. But not working very clearly.

```
String groupName = "Your Group Name";

 try {
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues groupValues = null;
            groupValues = new ContentValues();
            groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE,0);
            cr.update (ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE+ "=?", new String[]{groupName}) ;

            cr.delete(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE+ "=?", new String[]{groupValue});
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("########### Exception :",""+e.getMessage()); 
        }
```

After run this code. Group is deleted. I go to phones contacts or people and search  group. It is not shown. But **if I read all groups programmatically  in my program,** the deleted group shown.

Comment: You must apply query parameter `ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` with "true".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for delete group
 public void checkAndDeleteGroup(final GroupModel groupModel){

```
    Log.e("TAG", "Click on delete");
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> mOperations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    // Build the uri of your group with its id
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(groupModel.getGroup_id())).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .build();
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(uri);
    mOperations.add(builder.build());

    // Then apply batch
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, mOperations);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ProspectsActivity.this, "Group is not delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```