# When is the ANDROID Contact Group PHYSICALLY removed instead of being marked as deleted?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactgroups

I am trying to permanently remove a Android Contact Group and have used the Sync parameter and it always appears the record is simply marked as deleted and not physically removed. Can anyone explain how/when, if ever, the Contract group row is deleted permanently or show a snippet of code demonstrating how to do this? The records I am trying to remove are ones that I added, so they are not Read-Only.

Linked back to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376905/5398898

My Delete Code:

```
private void RemoveGroup()
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.helloworld);

    int[] startId = {10};//{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    String groupName = "My New Contacts";

    Uri mUri = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI;
    mUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();

    for (int n = 0; n < startId.length; n++) {

        groupCount = startId[n];

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactsContract.Groups._ID, groupCount);

        try {
            getContentResolver().delete(mUri, values.toString(),null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            tv.setText(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Result when reading the groups:**

Image can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OOfc.png

Comment: Thanks iago.  I didn't realize that buildUpon() did not append it to the URI.  PERFECT.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building the correct Uri but not using it, try like this

```
Uri mUri = ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI;
mUri = mUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
```